# How to represent hirerarical child-parent rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

Edit: [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/004df/1)

I have a `persons` table that contains these sample rows:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | name  | parent_id |
+----+-------+-----------+
| 1  | max   |  (null)   |
| 2  | payne |    1      |
| 3  | mike  |    1      |
| 4  | sara  |    2      |
| 7  | walt  |  (null)   |  
+----+-------+-----------+
```

Each person is listed only once, with a unique `ID` but can have a null value in `parent_id`. Some `child`s share the same `parent_id`.

I also have another `tickets` table that  store person information

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | request | person_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
| 1  |    1    |    1      |
| 2  |    1    |    3      |
| 3  |    2    |    2      |
| 4  |    2    |    3      |
| 5  |    2    |    7      |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Basically, each ticket can have multiple persons (per request). In this table, I don't store the `parent_id` since it can be retrieved from the `persons` table.

Now I tried to represent the `persons` hierarchy for request #2 using the following SQL statement

```
with x(id,name,parent_id)
as
(
   select 
        p.id,p.name,p.parent_id 
   from
        tickets t left join persons p on t.person_id = p.id
   where
            t.request=2
        and p.parent_id is null  /* for all parents */
  union all
  select
       c.id,c.name,c.parent_id
  from
       tickets j left join persons c on j.person_id = c.id
       join x on x.id = c.parent_id
  where
       j.request=2

) select * from x
```

But I get this error message:

> SQL Server Database Error: Outer join is not allowed in the recursive 
>   part of a recursive common table expression 'x'.

What mistake am I doing?

Comment: Build only the hierarchy with the `tickets` inside the CTE then join the `persons` table in the outer select (to the `x` "table")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need the `persons` table since it contains the `parent_id` information.. can you please elaborate?

Comment: A sorry. Then of course you need to build the hierarchy with the `persons` table and link the `tickets` table to the outer select.

Comment: You could maybe first join the `tickets` and `persons` table in a `cte` and then start a recursive cte?

Comment: Please use Answers for answers, these comments are only to get more information. Answers can then be rated, refined, and commented on.

Comment: Can you please give the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the tree in the CTE, then join the `tickets` table to the tree:

```
with person_tree (id, name, parent_id)
as
(
  select p.id, p.name, p.parent_id 
  from  persons p 
  where p.parent_id is null

  union all

  select c.id, c.name, c.parent_id
  from persons c 
    join person_tree p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select * 
from tickets t
  left join person_tree p on t.person_id = p.id
where t.request = 2;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/004df/28